# Showing read only /var partition on Debian

Tags: filesystems, readonly, fhs

I have seen an industrial computer running Debian, to protect the flash disk from writes and have the system in a defined state after every boot, the whole disk was mounted read-only, there are no other disks attached and no network storage. There are some services running, most notably Samba.

I tried to recreate that system for educational purposes, how can I stop any writes to disk, especially /var?

Just mounting as read-only breaks the system, as does mounting as tmpfs.

Comment: `mount -o remount,ro /var`

Comment: A read-only `/var` will break your system. It's called `/var` because it holds **var**iable data. Think of `/var/cache`, `/var/spool`, `/var/log` and so on. A very long time ago those were in `/etc` or `/usr`; then came the idea that `/usr` should be made read-only to enable diskless workstations and so was born `/var`...

Comment: why don't you want anything in `/var` to be written to disk?

Comment: I rephrased the question to be more clear what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the two approaches fail for very different reasons.

The `/var` filesystem hierarchy can not be mounted read-only since the system will be needing to write to it. There is no way around this.

Mounting it as a `tmpfs` filesystem seems like a good approach, but such a filesystem will be empty when mounted, and that will make the system fail in other ways.

This can still be a viable option, but you will have to make the system populate the empty `/var` hierarchy with the appropriate files and directories *straight after mounting it*, for example by untaring a pre-packed `/var.tar` file (or something), or recursively copying from an existing directory somewhere.

I'm not sure how to do that on Debian. OpenBSD has [a memory file system called MFS](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man8/newfs.8). When mounting an MFS filesystem, one has the option to pre-populate it with the contents of a directory or an FFS file system on a block device (this may even be done from the `/etc/fstab` file).

Obviously, the changes to the contents of `/var` while the machine is running won't be persistent between reboots without syncing it to an actual disk upon shutdown, which may or may not be a problem in your case.

Comment: Searching for memory file system led to OverlayFS and AuFS, which seem to do excatly what I need, thank you.